# how to put html tags into php serialized array

Tags: php

i have edited my codes below. when i universalize, i am not able to get html tags header and p tags.

```
$arr = array(
'header_txt' => '<h1>Text</h1>',
'title' => 'john',
'description' => '<p>john</p>',
'url' => 'links'); print '<pre>'; print_r(serialize($arr));print_r(unserialize(serialize($arr)));
```

Output of my code:

[image]

Comment: Kindly post the output of print_r($serialized) also.

Comment: spelling mistake. It's `$serialized`

Comment: in also typo `Json_encode($arr)` to `json_encode($arr)`

Comment: instead of `Json_encode` serialized with `serialize()` of php here is doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: if you are using `Json_encode()` then correnct syntax `json_encode()` and called encoded not serialized

Comment: najubudeendeveloper could you please check my answer and let me know issue solved or not?